# Receptive Field Size vs Object Size

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a question regarding the relationship between receptive field of a CNN and the object size it should detect. 
Lets say my objects have a size of 16x16 px. So should the receptive field be at least 16x16 ? Or should it be larger? Could it be bad if the receptive field is to large let's say in this case for example 100x100?

I know that this is a difficult question, but perhaps anyone has some experience on how big the receptive field should be in relationship to the object size.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The receptive field determines the amount of pixel that are considered in making a decision. If you use a subset of the object to determine if it is a specific subset it is like taking a crop and asking a human to determine what object it is, which is hard to do.

Generally it is helpful to consider the surrounding information to make an informed decision.

The only problem with using too much surrounding information is that the network might make decision based on something not related to the object itself, becuase it is correlated in the training set but not in real life. E.g. Car classification. You have a red background for every Audi and for no other car. So if you use the whole image as receptive field it will probably classify Audi based on the background and not on the car features.

Edit to your clarification:

I have done something similar with fingerprints. I would advise you to look at binary image segmentation and use a 6x6 region or something for every object so the loss function will be smoother. This worked best for my case.

This is a purely theoretical question because you will need a sufficient depth to archive good results anyways and the receptive field will be larger than the object anyways. Furthermore because the object can change its size no fixed receptive size works for all the objects in the scene. Still it would be an interesting experiment if it helps limiting the receptive size for a pixel. I do not think so.

Comment: Okay, I understand that in this case of classification larger objects it makes sense, that the filter size should not be to small and not to large. My case is more like a density estimation problem. Lets consider I have cells of size 10x10 - 16x16 in an image. And my image patch is 72x72 large. If my effective receptive field (through many 3x3 filters + pooling layers) in the last layer would cover the whole 72x72 image patch, and as an example the image patch has one cell in the middle, then every neuron in the last layer would have the same value ??

Comment: Why would you not crop the images into the right size so you do not need to worry about the reception field? I mean extracting the single cells and just feeding them into the network.

Comment: With the one cell in the middle of the image patch was just an example. The image could look like this: [https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/77/4b/09/774b098dd3e9eec4884701d97c93d47b.jpg] So there could be also a half of a cell or bigger/smaller ones and also overlapping etc...

Comment: But what do you want to do? Find every cell in the image?

Comment: Yeah, so a density estimation. The label (groundtruth) is a 2D matrix where every center of a cell is annoted with a dot and a gaussian is used on every dot to get a density map as groundtruth

Answer (score 0):

The *best* relative size for your receptive field will depend on the overall architecture of your network. But generally speaking, you probably should have the filter receptive field smaller than the size of the object you want to detect. Assuming you have a layer with a sufficient number of convolutional filters, you want the receptive field sized so that the filters can detect the *features* (edges, colors, textures, etc.) of the object. Subsequent layers of your CNN will then combine the features to detect the aggregate object.

For example, see [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/). The figure captioned "Example filters..." shows the learned convolutional filters, which have receptive fields of 11x11 pixels, whereas the object to be detected (a car in this case) spans hundreds of pixels.

Comment: Yeah but the 11x11 filter is not the final receptive field. It could be the receptive field in the first layer, but when there are many layers stacked the receptive field grows. So it can be that in the last layer with a filter of 3x3 the effective receptive field of this layer can cover 200x200pixels in the original image and so it covers almost the whole car.

Comment: I see - you're referring to the effective receptive field of the final convolutional layer. I don't think there is a need to have your final receptive field be larger than the object but the performance of the network will then likely depend more heavily on how you have structured the fully-connected (or other) layers beyond the convolutional layers.